# Is there a way to import code into a Babel source block from an external file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, babeljs

I am specifically interested in [Literate Programming](http://howardism.org/Technical/LP/introduction.html) in which the documentation and source code are in one file.  Org-Mode has support for Babel's ability to embed source code blocks. One shortcoming is that syntactical highlighting doesn't work, and you can't take advantage of the full Language-mode features when the block is in Org-Mode.

Babel supports 'tangling' source code, which copies the source code into a named file, such as test.py. I am looking for a solution which will let me develop the source code in a fully featured Language-Mode, while being able to document that code, explaining the 'Why', in org mode.

Comment: In a code block, type C-c ' to edit the block in its native mode. Also, use (setq org-src-fontify-natively t) in an init file so that the code blocks are syntax highlighted.

Comment: Alternatively, consider the lentic package: https://github.com/phillord/lentic which allows you to switch back and forth between views in org-mode and views in the program mode.

Comment: Lentic seems like a good solution to essentially have the best of both worlds.  I'll test it some to see if it can handle multiple org files (perhaps as includes at the top, depending on the language).

Comment: I got Lentic setup, but it seems to have some stability issues.  When editing the python source, it occasionally corrupts the source org with python comments.

Comment: I suspect stability issues are likely  in any approach that allows "split brain" between two source files. That's why git sometimes requires manual operations before a merge will go through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `<body>` of a source code block

```
 #+NAME: <name>
 #+BEGIN_SRC <language> <switches> <header arguments>
   <body>
 #+END_SRC
```

`C-c '` will open a buffer in the appropriate major mode for `<language>`. The *Babel* documentation is [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-source-code.html#Editing-source-code).

Comment: Yes, C-c ' will open a buffer with the appropriate major mode, but it doesn't allow you to import code into an org file (to primarily make all changes to the external file, and import the updated changes into the org mode file).

Comment: @TeddyNguyen A file can be `#+INCLUDE`d into an org file, of course, and show up in the exported document. I suspect that the reason that org-mode Babel doesn't support the workflow you are looking for is because there is no single point of truth: `tangle` writes to the external file and the external file would write back to the code block. If there' s a conflict, which is correct? In CAP terms, the system is CP. It's probably helpful to think in terms of data and persistence rather than files, anyway. Again, there's always `#+INCLUDE` if you want the external file to be canonical.

Comment: @TeddyNguyen the Emacs function insert-file will insert a file at point. CAP is a non-issue here since you are the only user and your org-mode buffer is the single source of truth. If you're using a language with a toolchain that initially stubs-out source files with code generation, and you want to insert the stubs into your literate org-mode buffer within source blocks to develop them further with noweb, then this approach will work fine. If the toolchain subsequently modifies source files after initially stubbing them out at some later date, then there would be a problem here.